# Error 1 The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, while-loop, int

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int f = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("enter ammount of tries");
        int trycount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Random numgen = new Random();
        while (f < trycount)
        {
            int now = numgen.Next(1, 6);
            int avg = 0 + now;
            f++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(avg);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

problem is when I try to run the program it says that the name:

> 'avg' does not exist in the current context

Why is this happening and how can I fix it.

Comment: Define average out of the scope of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `avg` inside the scope of the loop and thus it does not exist outside of the scope. *(also when you assign the new value to `avg` do not replace the existing value but use `+=` to increase the existing value)*

Fix:

```
int avg = 0;
while (f < trycount)
{
    int now = numgen.Next(1, 6);
    avg += now;
    f++;
}
```

In addition remember when printing the average to divide it by the number of items added: *(remember to cast one of the operands to a type that holds decimal points and not `int` - so you will get the real average and not a rounded `int`version of it)*

```
Console.WriteLine(avg/(double)f);
```

Please refer to Scopes in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx) to understand more when and where variables and methods are accessibe.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the "avg" variable within the escope of "while". Anything outside that scope can't see the variable.

You should declare your avg variable outside the while.

Answer (score 0):

If declare the variable inside the while loop it can throws an error as "The name "avg" cannot exist in the current context". Because you can declare within the while loop, when the condition cannot satisfied in the while loop the variable cannot defined and declare so at the time printing the result it can throws an error.

So we can defined the variable outside the while loop.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             int f = 0,avg=0;
             Console.WriteLine("enter ammount of tries");
             int trycount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
             Random numgen = new Random();
             while (f < trycount)
             {
                 int now = numgen.Next(1, 6);
                 avg = 0 + now;
                 f++;
             }
             Console.WriteLine(avg);
             Console.ReadLine();
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, see comments:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter amount of tries"); // typo
        int TryCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Random numgen = new Random();

        // it is sum we compute in the loop (add up values), not average
        // double: final average will be double: say 2 tries 4 and 5 -> 4.5 avg
        // please notice, that sum is declared out of the loop's scope 
        double sum = 0.0; 

        // for loop looks much more natural in the context then while one
        for (int i = 0; i < TryCount; ++i)
          sum += numgen.Next(1, 6);

        // we want to compute the average, right? i.e. sum / TryCount
        Console.WriteLine(sum / TryCount);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Just for reference: in real life we usually use *Linq* which is more compact and *readable*:

```
Console.WriteLine("enter amount of tries"); // typo
int TryCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Random numgen = new Random(); 

Console.Write(Enumerable
  .Range(0, TryCount)
  .Average(x => numgen.Next(1, 6)));

Console.ReadLine();
```